# Jenkins sending invalid input to console of application

Tags: c++, windows, jenkins, console

I am running a very simple Jenkins project on Windows that just calls an executable. The executable just reads in user input from the console and prints it back to the console. It has the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int selection = 0;

  while (true)
  {
    std::cin >> selection;
    std::cout << "selection was: " << selection << '\n';

    if (std::cin.fail())
    {
      std::cin.clear();
      std::cin.ignore();
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If I run this application **outside** of Jenkins, it only completes a loop iteration if I manually enter an input into the console (as expected).

```
1
selection was: 1
2
selection was: 2
3
selection was: 3
4
selection was: 4
5
selection was: 5
```

However, if I run it **inside** Jenkins, without providing input manually, then the exe gets spammed non-stop / very rapidly with invalid input.

```
selection was: 0
selection was: 0
selection was: 0
selection was: 0
selection was: 0
selection was: 0
selection was: 0
selection was: 0
selection was: 0
selection was: 0
....repeated many times
```

The `std::cin` call should block until input is received. Does anyone know what the source of the input is, or how to stop it? My assumption is that it must be something in Jenkins, since of course.. the issue doesn't exist when running outside Jenkins.

Thanks!

Comment: _"Does anyone know what the source of the input is"_. The behavior you describe would also happen if there were no input, but `std::cin >> selection` immediately fails.  Perhaps STDIN is mapped to /dev/null?

Comment: Is there a way to check if STDIN is mapped to /dev/null? I should have mentioned that this is on Windows as well.